# is simple_salesforce equivalent to requests.post()?

Tags: api, simple-salesforce

i'm new to salesforce api. My colleague gave us sample code like

```
params = {
    "grant_type": ,
    "client_id": ,
    "client_secret": ,
    "username": ,
    "password": # Concatination of password + security token
}
r = requests.post("https://login.salesforce.com/xxxxxx", params=params)
```

Is `simple_salesforce` a wrapper of above `request`-based api interaction?

Ie, for SF admin, is the api setup same when it's used by `simple_salesforce` vs used by `request` connection?

I've looked at [salesforce git](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/blob/master/simple_salesforce/api.py) and it looks like it's equivalent (a wrapper) of `request` things

Comment: basically yes. But its hard to know why you want to know that based on your post

Comment: thanks @booky99!  If i know they are the same under the hood, i can use `simple_salesforce` which i'm familiar about. Otherwise i need to stick with `request` and figure out the following `get` methods. (Right now neither is working, so I know very little things. That's why I asked here to make sure of one thing to start with)